# Retrieve data from table using data retrieved from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the id from one table in a database and use that id as a "key" in order to get the name from another table.
For example

```
 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE id=8 ") 
 or die(mysql_error());  

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {

echo $row['client_id'];
```

Here i get the client_id from the table 1.
Now how do i implement that into this so that it returns the name and last name only of those that have the above id

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM YYY WHERE ???? :S ") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
   { 
   Print "<tr>"; 
   Print "<th>fname:</th> <td>".$info['firstname'] . "</td> "; 
   Print "<th>lname:</th> <td>".$info['lastname'] . " </td></tr>"; 
} 
Print "</table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Why don't you use join ? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: ended up using "$data = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM YYY WHERE id IN (SELECT client_id FROM XXX WHERE id=8 )")"

thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to take the client_id from `XXX` table, use a subquery:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM YYY WHERE id IN (SELECT client_id FROM XXX WHERE id=8 )") .
```

If `XXX.id` is PRIMARY KEY, then that subquery will return just one row, so instead if using `id IN (SEL...)`, use `id = (SEL...`

Comment: If you're done, close this question by accepting an answer :).

Comment: sure thing, i just notified me i had to wait some minutes before i do :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM YYY WHERE id ". $row['client_id']) ;
or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  SELECT firstname, lastname FROM YYY WHERE id IN (SELECT client_id FROM XXX WHERE id=8 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the question:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM YYY WHERE client_id = ".$row['client_id']."";
```

But, as mentioned, do not use mysql_ functions, ase they are deprecated and will be removed in the future. This means that your code won't be running for a long time if you still use them.

Also, I guess it would be more efficient and more elegant to solve this with MySQL [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)s. 
If you have difficulty in implementing this, just ask for help.

A simple example for a query with a JOIN is the following:

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
  yy.firstname, yy.lastname 
FROM xx 
JOIN yy ON yy.client_id = xx.client_id 
WHERE xx.id = ".$yourID."
";
```